# How come hibernate executes update sql statements when I do a read using HQL on the same object/table?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, transactions, locking

What's happening is i'm performing a read of some records, say Car where color = red, and it returns 10 cars. Then I iterate over those 10 cars, and update a date in that car object, i.e. car.setDate(5/1/2010). Then I perform another read from Cars where color = green. I have sql logging turned on and I noticed when i call query.list() it actually prints out some update statements to the Cars table, and I end up getting a lock wait timeout. Also note, this is all done in a single database transaction, so I can understand the lock wait timeout - it seems like i have a lock on the table i'm reading from, and in that same transaction i'm trying to update it before i release the lock on the table. But it seems like it shouldn't be trying to run the sql to update those records until the end of the transaction when i call commit? This is all using hibernate's HQL to perform the reads. I'm not calling anything directly at all to do the saves, i'm just doing car.setDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database writes are controlled by the FlushMode on your session. By default, hibernate uses `FlushMode.AUTO`, which allows it to perform a `session.flush()` whenever it sees fit. A `session.flush()` causes uncommitted data on the session to be written to the database. Flushing session data to the database does not make it permanent until you commit your session (or roll it back). Depending on your database Table/Row locking strategy, the rows that have been updated as part of this transaction may be locked for Read or Read/Write access.

I think the answer is in the database- do your tables have the appropriate locking strategy that supports your use case?